# Trying to create a looping cards in php (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

im fairly new in php and mysqli and trying to make some basic website.

basically i want to make a looping statement in php to create cards in the same row with same size and col without myself creating the cards manually in html.

using bootstrap, php and mysqli

the code is successfully running, but the output doesnt match the bootstrap cards, and they refuse to be in the same row

can anyone help me ? thank you

```html
<?php include("conn.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/ArdiantaPargo.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <?php include("header.php"); ?>
        </header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default"><?php include("menu.php"); ?></nav>

        <article>

        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">

                    

                        <!-- article ------------------->
                        <?php

                            $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY datae DESC");

                            // looping Artikel
                            while($artikel = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                                echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                                echo "<a class='card-title' href='artikel.php?id=".$artikel['id']."' />".$title['title']."</a>";
                                echo "<p class='article-date'>Oleh <b>".$author['author']."</b>, pada ".$article['date']."</p>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            }

                        ?>
                        <!-- END article --------------->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </article>

        <footer>
            <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you left part of your card out of your loop. I'm guessing you've got one `<div class="card">` containing many `<div class="card-body">`s.

I would leave the `<div class="row">` out of your loop, but everything inside that should be part of the loop.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php

                        $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY datae DESC");

                        // looping Artikel
                        while($artikel = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                            echo "<div class='col-12 col-md-4'>";
                            echo "<div class='card mb-4 shadow-sm'>";
                            echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                            echo "<a class='card-title' href='artikel.php?id=".$artikel['id']."' />".$title['title']."</a>";
                            echo "<p class='article-date'>Oleh <b>".$author['author']."</b>, pada ".$article['date']."</p>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        }

                    ?>
</div>
```